# Azure Key Vault Certificate Management using Java

Tags: java, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-keyvault

My solution involves creation of a certificate in keyvault using Java. Below are the ways I tried to do it but was not successful.

1. **DefaultAzureCredentialBuilder**:The most basic form of creation of the certificate wherein I have to export the clientId, clientSecret and the tenantId in the environment variables and create a Certificate Client as below:

```
  CertificateClient certificateClient = new CertificateClientBuilder()
                                   .vaultUrl("https://valueUrl.vault.azure.net")
                                  .credential(new DefaultAzureCredentialBuilder().build()).buildClient();
```

2. **ADAL**: This is the one I am more interested in as I can send in my details of client id, secret and tenantid and then instantiate the certificate client. I tried using this and still was not successful. The snippet is as below:

```
     ClientCertificateCredential certCreds = new ClientCertificateCredentialBuilder()
                        .clientId("clientId")
                        .pfxCertificate("C:\\MyCerft.pfx", "123")
                        .tenantId("tenantId").build();
     CertificateClient certificateClient1 = new CertificateClientBuilder()
                        .vaultUrl("https://vaultUrl.vault.azure.net/")
                        .credential(certCreds).buildClient();
```

The source of the samples are from below:

- https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/tree/master/sdk/keyvault/azure-security-keyvault-certificates
- https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/tree/master/sdk/identity/azure-identity

But both the above throw out the same error of mismatch in signature in the credentialBuilder class as

```
com.azure.security.keyvault.certificates.CertificateClientBuilder"'s signer information does not match
signer information of other classes in the same package
```

Below is dependencies in my pom file:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
  <artifactId>azure-security-keyvault-certificates</artifactId>
  <version>4.0.0</version>
</dependency>    `

<dependency>
  <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
  <artifactId>azure-identity</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.4</version> <!-- {x-version-update;com.azure:azure-identity;dependency} -->
</dependency>
```

I would really like to do it the second way as that is much safer and lets me do some config settings that I have to set in the first case. But, at this point, I would even take the first, in case there is an outcome there.

Also, I do not understand why for the second way, microsoft haven't given the client secret as a parameter but expect a certificate(pfx/pem) to the solution to authenticate. As, I believe the sdk should allow accept both ways of access.

Any suggestions on what am I possibly missing here would be of great help as this is something I picked straight from the official documentation from Microsoft.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

It could be a BUG. I resolved it by using SDKs of the following version:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.azure/azure-identity -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
    <artifactId>azure-identity</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0-beta.2</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.azure/azure-security-keyvault-certificates -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
    <artifactId>azure-security-keyvault-certificates</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.0-beta.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your input. I tried putting this in. It is not working. The same error resurfaces.Edit: This has typically worked for you in the first case or the second one?